# Forward declared enum as class member variable

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, enum-class

As a rule of thumb on forward declaration (from "API Design for C++", p. 214), I only include the header of a class if I:

- use an **object** of that class as a **data member** in my own class, or
- **inherit** from that class.

In all rest cases I just forward declare the class.

However, I recently used by accident as a data member of a class a *forward declared enum* class, and it compiled.

Is this indeed ok to use, or a just an accidental hack (and I actually need the header with the definition of MyEnum)?

```
// test.hpp
enum class MyEnum;

class A {
    MyEnum myenum;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forward declared enum class has a specified underlying type. If not explicitly specified it is `int`. Because of that the storage size of the enum is known, even if it's only forward declared, so using it as a member is not a problem.

Comment: But if the actual enum definition has a specified type (or it is changed later, after I have forward-declared the enum in my file), e.g. `enum class MyEnum: char { VAL1, VAL2 };` will this still be ok?

Comment: That's not allowed. If the type is not specified in the forward declaration it is `int`.

Comment: So, if initially the type was not specified in definition, everything is ok. If later someone specifies the enum type in definition to be `char`, will she get a compilation error? Also, will all forward declarations need to be changed to also specify the underlying enum type?

Comment: Yes. [Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NraFXFB1cbJVx2GJ).